# How to check if the value from array of object is equal to certain value using cypress?

Tags: cypress

Hi i have an array of object like so,

```
const arr_obj = [
    {
         value: '100',
         id: '1',
    }
]


cypress test code is like below,

it('some test' , () => {
   const expectedValue = 200;
   cy.apiGetObject(id).then((arr_obj) => {
       expect(arr_obj[0].value).should('eq', expectedValue);
   }
```

});

i have to tried to check if arr_obj[0].value is equal to expectedValue like above. but it gives error

invalid chai property should

how should i check with cypress if the arr_obj[0].value and expectedValue are same.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect` and `should` are two different types of assertions and cannot be used  together.

So in case if you want to use `expect` you have to use:

```js
expect(arr_obj[0].value).to.equal(expectedValue)
```

And in case you want to use `should`, you can do:

```js
cy.wrap(arr_obj[0].value).should('eq', expectedValue)
```